# Трансляция экрана

Tags: mysql, php, html, javascript, actionscript

Подскажите, как на любом языке программирования, даже на action script или просто Flash, короче, любым способом транслировать на сайт видео с экрана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто записать картинку, то выберите что-то из гугла по запросу: "захват видео с экрана".

Если же интересно, как это работает)

Есть ряд софта: входящий в windows server - Windows Media Services, RealNet Helix Server, Adobe Flash Media Streaming Server 4.5 и т.п.

Даже было что-то бесплатное на базе VLC....
Вот ещё попалась ссылка на http://www.umediaserver.net/

Этот софт кодирует поток и в реальном времени шлет его через инет.
Естественно полоса инета тратится по-полной на каждого клиента.

Они все умеют работать с web-камерой, TV-тюнером, TV-входом на видюхе и конечно с полноценными картами захвата.

Насчет с экрана - мы игрались в связку комп(экран)->ТВ-выход->Карта захвата-> MS Stream Server. 
В принципе было неплохо. Самописная софтина довольно знатно переключала камеру и медиа-плеер))

Но вообще задача гиморна.

Comment: Плеер для каждого свой, практически. Естественно, машина, которая кодирует должна иметь реальный IP и толстый канал.